# How do I write titles for regions in the intersection of two functions?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose `c` is in `[0,0.5]` and `r=sqrt(c)`.

I am using the following code to fill the region between `0` and `r`, and I want to write the label inside this region in the figure:

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharex=True);
ax1.fill_between(c, 0, r, label='region 1 ')
```

How is it possible to do this?

Also, when I set `c=constant`, it results in a line, and I am willing to show it as a solid line with a legend. How can I do this?

Happy New Year!

Comment: Welcome to SO and Happy New Year to you, too. What does `c in [0,0.5]` mean? Is that `c=np.linspace(0, 0.5, 100)` or similar? Matplotlib has an [extensive description of how to annotate plots](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/annotation_demo.html). Have you tried any of those at the coordinate c/2, r(c/2)/2? If so, what were the specific problems you encountered? Regarding the line - that is `plt.plot(c, c, label="line")`.

Answer (score 0):

With `ax.legend()` a legend can be added for each plot command with a `label=...`. `bbox_to_anchor=(x,y)` can set an anchor point `x,y` which are measured in ['axes coordinates'](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) (which run from the left plot border to 1 at the right, and from 0 at the bottom to 1 at the top). `loc=` tells which point of the legend's bounding box will be positioned at the anchor.

`ax.axhline()` draws a constant horizontal line.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

c = np.linspace(0, 0.5)
r = np.sqrt(c)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
ax1.fill_between(c, 0, r, label='region 1')
ax1.legend(loc='lower right', bbox_to_anchor=(0.8, 0.2), facecolor='ivory', framealpha=0.9)
ax1.margins(x=0, y=0)
constant = 0.5
ax2.axhline(np.sqrt(constant), label=f'sqrt of {constant}', lw=2)
ax2.legend()
ax2.set_xlim(0, 0.5)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]